# Why is vertical distance the standard in least squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, statistics, intuition, least-squares

When fitting a curve in $\mathbb R^2$ to data points in $\mathbb R^2$ ([example](https://youtu.be/6eWF6AoVK8w?t=9m28s)), why is each point's vertical distance from the curve squared instead of its shortest (possibly diagonal) distance from the curve?

Ignoring my poorly drawn curves, it seems obvious that [image: https://i.imgur.com/vy6ioMg.png] is a worse curve-to-point fit than [image: https://i.imgur.com/9m22M8p.png] even though the red line is shorter in the first image, because you can draw the much shorter blue line instead (which I labeled b in the second image).  Minimizing $b^2$ seems much more important than minimizing $a^2$.

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPerpendicularOffsets.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, diagonal distance is used in some cases.

From the operative point of view, the standard "vertical" distance is taken when it is assumed that in the 2D data available, the $x$ has been measured (almost) exactly, while the $y$ is subject to error.

When both $x$ and $y$ are subject to error, under the usual assumptions of independence, near Gaussian distribution, etc. the distance  shall be taken along a line with slope $\sigma_y / \sigma_x$.

That's called [Total least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares).

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind many examples of least-squares fit is to use it as a predictive model: given some points $\{(x_1,y_1), \dots, (x_n,y_n)\}$, you find a curve that takes an input $x$ and gives you a predicted value of $f(x)$.

In this case, the vertical distance $|y_1 - f(x_1)|$ is the difference between the actual known value $y_1$ and the predicted value $f(x_1)$. (And $(y_1 - f(x_1))^2$ is the squared error.) This is the actual measurement of error we care about, because it's a prediction of how far off we'll be if we guess $f(x)$ for a different value $x$.

Comment: Yes, but .. to estimate $f(x)$ you need to know / assume how the data are prone to errors !

Answer (score 1):

Your data points are $(x_i, y_i)$ and your regression line is $y=mx+b.$

The  absolute error in estimation at each point is $|y_i -mx_i-b|$ which is the vertical distance from your data point to your regression line.

Comment: You would not get the same line, because it's possible that the new optimal line would have a different slope. Even if you're comparing *vertical* distances and *horizontal* distances, the best-fit lines can be different, and the best-diagonal-distance line is a compromise between both.